# I have a complex design, I don't know what to do with flutter,

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I have a complex design, I don't know what to do with flutter, is there any help on how to implement this design?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to achieve a shape and the center painter here. Few things, I am able to achieve but for complete part, I think you need to use pie chart https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts specially Doughnut type.

Please check my sample as below:

This painter is used to prepare the pie.

```
class WheelPainter extends CustomPainter {
  Path getWheelPath(double wheelSize, double fromRadius, double toRadius) {
    return new Path()
      ..moveTo(wheelSize, wheelSize)
      ..arcTo(
          Rect.fromCircle(
              radius: wheelSize, center: Offset(wheelSize, wheelSize)),
          fromRadius,
          toRadius,
          false)
      ..close();
  }

  Paint getColoredPaint(Color color) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = color;
    return paint;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double wheelSize = 150;
    double nbElem = 6;
    double radius = (2 * pi) / nbElem;

    // canvas.drawPath(getWheelPath(wheelSize, 0, radius), getColoredPaint(Colors.red));
    canvas.drawShadow(getWheelPath(wheelSize, radius * 0.5, radius * 2).shift(Offset(0, -10)), Colors.black, 10.0, true);
    canvas.drawPath(getWheelPath(wheelSize, radius * 0.5, radius * 2),
        getColoredPaint(Colors.purple));

    // canvas.drawPath(getWheelPath(wheelSize, radius * 2, radius), getColoredPaint(Colors.blue));
    canvas.drawShadow(getWheelPath(wheelSize, radius * 2.7, radius * 1.7).shift(Offset(0, -10)), Colors.black, 10.0, true);
    canvas.drawPath(getWheelPath(wheelSize, radius * 2.7, radius * 1.7),
        getColoredPaint(Colors.green));
    // canvas.drawPath(getWheelPath(wheelSize, radius * 4, radius), getColoredPaint(Colors.yellow));
    canvas.drawShadow(getWheelPath(wheelSize, radius * 4.6, radius * 1.7).shift(Offset(0, -10)), Colors.black, 10.0, true);
    canvas.drawPath(getWheelPath(wheelSize, radius * 4.6, radius * 1.7),
        getColoredPaint(Colors.orange));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate != this;
  }
}
```

Below is the sample to use it.

```
Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
        CustomPaint(
          size: Size(300, 300),
          painter: WheelPainter(),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 150,
          height: 150,
          decoration:
              BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 110,
          height: 110,
          decoration:

          BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey,
                blurRadius: 10.0,
                blurStyle: BlurStyle.outer,
                spreadRadius: 3.0,
                offset: Offset(1.0,1.0)
            )
          ]),
        )
      ]),
```

This is how it will look like.

[image]

Hope it may help you.

Comment: This is very convenient but I don't know how to include a child text in it

Answer (score 3):

Usually to create complex designs I prefer using [Flutter Shape Maker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/).
All you need is to upload your svg picture and it will convert it to CustomPaint code in flutter. Perhaps this may help you.

Comment: It solved my big problem which is not related to this question but it helps me a lot.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

```
You can take two container in Stack Widget
and implement customPaint
```

[customPaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994068/flutter-draw-a-circle-border-with-3-multiple-colors-and-values)

Answer (score 0):

You can try packges from pub.dev for this and you can customise as you need in app this designs.

[syncfusion_flutter-chart](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts)

Try above package for your requirements